# ReactJS passing input data from child to parent

Tags: reactjs

Good day. I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass input data from Child component to parent.

**P.S**

If there is a more appropriate way in managng the components data, i'm free to opened suggestions.

**The Child**

```
class CustomEmailInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }



    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <CssTextField
                    className={classes.margin}
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    autoComplete="email"
                    onChange={this.props.setMail}
                    InputProps={{
                        className: classes.input
                    }}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        className: classes.labelInput
                    }}
                    label="Email"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(CustomEmailInput);
```

**The Parent**

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        };
        this.handleData = this.handleData.bind(this);
        this.setEmail = this.setEmail.bind(this);
    }

    handleData = props => {
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        console.log(email, password)
    };


    setEmail = (data) => {
        this.setState({
            email: data
        });
        console.log(data)
    };





    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.bg}>
                <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs" pt={5}>
                    <CssBaseline/>
                    <div className={classes.paper}>
                        <Typography
                            component="h1"
                            variant="h5"
                            style={{color: 'white'}}
                        >
                            Sign in
                        </Typography>
                        <form className={classes.form}>
                            <MyEmailField
                                setMail={this.setEmail}
                            />
                            <MyPasswordField
                                // setPassword={this.setPassword}
                                label="Password"
                            />
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                fullWidth
                                variant="contained"
                                color="default"
                                className={classes.submit}
                                onClick={this.handleData}
                            >
                                Sign In
                            </Button>
                            <Grid container>
                                <Grid item xs>
                                    <Link
                                        to="/reset"
                                        variant="body1"
                                        className={classes.btn_forgot}
                                        style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}
                                    >
                                        Forgot password?
                                    </Link>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item>
                                    <Link
                                        to="/register"
                                        variant="body2"
                                        className={classes  .btn_register}
                                        style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}
                                    >
                                        {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                                    </Link>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(SignIn);
```

I'm using `material-UI`, would it be better to change the child component to functional component?

Comment: What information should be passed to the parent?

Comment: For this component the email

Comment: @SomoKRoceS There still is no accepted answer. Mind doing the honors? :)

Comment: Have you tried what I wrote in the comments on my answer? What exactly do you get as an error, what the `console.log` on `setEmail` prints when you change value?

Comment: @SomoKRoceS Yes, log from setMail is empy string, log from submit is some object without `email` and `password` data

Answer (score 0):

The practice, which I can see you are using in this code, is setting the state of the parent by passing to the children a function that triggers `setState` (You're doing it with `setEmail`) and then call that function in child component to update parent's state.

(Another ways includes using [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) or [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started))

Comment: Would you be so kind and modify the code, i'm just starting out with react and really tried everything but don't really understand why it's not working.

Comment: Actually I see that you are using `MyEmailField` instead of `CustomEmailInput`. it might be the problem. Try using the right component name in the form instead of `<MyEmailField`

Answer (score 0):

first off all you should try the [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) pattern for your application, this way communication between components is not more up to the component itself. You will have an architecture dealing with this.

Dealing with your problem, a solution is to create a function in your parent that receives the input as parameter and pass it by props to the child, then you just have to call it inside the child at some event (onChange like you are doing).